# VSCode: keep focus in Source Control Viewlet when opening a file

Tags: visual-studio-code

I want to be able to navigate through all my file changes efficiently via only using my keyboard.

When I open the source control view and navigate through the changes with the arrow keys and press `enter` then the source control view loses focus and opens the file. I want to be able to just preview the file changes without losing the focus from the source control view.

E.g.:

press `enter` → view `file-change-1.txt` → press `key down` then `enter` → view `file-chang-2.txt`

What happens now, is when I press enter when a file is highlighted the file diff is open, but the focus from the source control is lost. So when I press down and enter then an actual `\n` is written into the open file.

I tried adding the following keyboard shortcut to my `keybindings.json` in order to preview files using the space key

```
{
    "key": "space",
    "command":"filesExplorer.openFilePreserveFocus",
    "when":"sideBarFocus && activeViewlet == 'workbench.view.scm'"
}
```

This doesn't work. I think the `filesExplorer.openFilePreserveFocus` only works in the file explorer viewlet.

Is it possible to achieve this behaviour?

Answer (score 2):

Also see this coming in v1.48:

> As you navigate the Source Control view, pressing <kbd>Space</kbd> on a change
> will now open it as a preview editor and keep the focus in the Source
> Control view, for easier keyboard navigation.

You <kbd>downarrow</kbd> through your scm file changes and hit <kbd>Space</kbd> to open a diff view.  Focus remains in the SCM view so you could keep doing this.

Comment: In 1.47 this behaviour works in the File Explorer viewlet. I was expecting the same behaviour in the SCM view, but for some reason it doesn't work like that there. I'll just wait and see once 1.48 is released, then maybe I can also remove the setting from `keybindings.json`

Comment: Works for me in v1.73

Answer (score 0):

Release 1.47 has a `command` called `list.selectAndPreserveFocus`. This should make it work:

```
{ 
    "key": "space",
    "command": "list.selectAndPreserveFocus",
    "when": "sideBarFocus && activeViewlet == 'workbench.view.scm'"
}
```